# Dynamic URLs w/ Struts 1

Tags: java, struts, apache

I'm using Struts 1.  I have a list of stores in our database. The store table contains store id, store name, url friendly store path, store address.  For example, "1; Store 1; the-wonderful-store; 52 Main St.",

When a request comes in for /store/the-wonderful-store.do, I want to grab "the-wonderful-store" and query the DB for the store for this path.  Now render the page with this query result.

The page uses tiles for its template.

How can I do this with Struts 1?

And if not, since I front this with Apache2, is it safe to just

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /store/(.*) /store.do?path=$1 [NC,PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [URLRewrite filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). It will allows the users to send in requests like /store/the-wonderful-store and the rewrite filter can forward this to your action passing in needed data from the url to your action like `showStore.do?name=the-wonderful-store`

In this way you will have all the logic for displaying stores in one Action and URLRewrite Filter will forward the matching requests as you want.

Check out their [documentation](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html) for more information.

Comment: +1 URLRewrite Filter is sort of the mod_rewrite for java world. You can use mod_rewrite for apache as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in your mapping. And from there you can check the requested URL to get your information.

---

**Resources :**

- [struts.apache.org - Using Wildcards in ActionMappings](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html#a4.10_Using_Wildcards_in_ActionMappings)